# Trying to understand context in arrays/list in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, list

I am trying to understand the context (array/list/scalar) in `Perl`.
I tried the following:

```
@array = qw (john bill george);  
print @array;  
print "\n";  
@sorted = sort (array);  
print @sorted;
```

1. Why does the `print @array` concats the quoted words? I need to `print
   "@array";`  to print the list? I mean `@` signifies an array right?
   So why are the quoted needed for print?
2. Why does the `print @sorted;` prints `array`?  If it is treated as a
   scalar shouldn't it print `3` which is the size of the array?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;` in your programs. If you had, this would have told you `Unquoted string "array" may clash with future reserved word at...`, which is a warning you get when using barewords such as `array`.

Answer (score 4):

`print @sorted` prints "array" because you forgot the `@` in the previous line :P
Change `sort(array)` to `sort(@array)` and it will print "billgeorgejohn".

As for why does `print @array` concatenate the quoted words, first let's make sure we're on the same page regarding `qw`:

```
@array = qw(john bill george);
```

is equivalent to

```
@array = ("john", "bill", "george");
```

so you're getting an array of three elements. Next, see [the documentation for `print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html). Passing a list of stuff to `print` will print them all, in order, separated by whatever value `$,` (the output field separator) has at the time. The default is empty string.

So you could do:

```
$, = " ";
print @array;
```

to get "john bill george".

Comment: I know that I did not use `@`.My question is why didn't it print 3.I thought that in scalar context we get the size of the array.Not its name

Comment: `print` can take a scalar or a list, with list being the default, so to force scalar context, you must do `print scalar @array`. Omitting the `@` just makes it a bareword. In places where scalar context is the only one possible you would still use `@array`, for example `if (@array == 3) { print "size is 3"; }` is valid code for checking if the size is 3.

Comment: @Cratylus It didn't print its name. It printed the word that you gave it. `array` has nothing whatsoever to do with the array `@array`. They are two completely different things. Also, `print` imposes a list context, not scalar.

Comment: So `array` is considered a string?

Comment: `array` is a bareword, which becomes a string or an error depending on whether or not you `use warnings` and `use strict` or not.

Comment: @Cratylus Its a bareword, meaning it can be a number of things: A subroutine, a file handle.. or a string, if none of the other things it can be is found. If you want to refer to your array, you can't omit the sigil `@`.

Comment: @miorel: `print` *always* takes a list. It may have only one element in it, but it's a list.

Answer (score 2):

The function `print` takes a list of arguments and prints those arguments.

If you explicitly pass a list to `print` then I hope you're not surprised when it prints out the elements of that list without spaces between them.

```
print 'one', 'two', 'three'; # prints "onetwothree
```

Passing an array to `print` is exactly the same. The contents of the array are converted to a list and then passed to `print`;

```
my @array = qw(one two three);
print @array; # prints "onetwothree"
```

In both of those cases, `print` receives three arguments and prints those arguments with nothing separating them.

Actually, Perl uses the special variable `$,` to control what `print` outputs between its arguments. By default that's an empty string, but you can change it.

Now let's consider your other case.

```
my @array = qw(one two three);
print "@array"; # prints "one two three"
```

How many arguments does `print` get in this example? Well, it's just one, isn't it? It's a single double quoted string. And when Perl sees a double quoted string it expands any variables in the string. The result of that expansion is then passed to `print` which then prints it. So we need to find out how Perl expands arrays in double-quoted. That's defined in the [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) manual page.

> **Array Interpolation**
>
> Arrays and slices are interpolated into double-quoted strings by
>   joining the elements with the delimiter specified in the $" variable
>   ($LIST_SEPARATOR if "use English;" is specified), space by default.

So, by default, Perl interpolates arrays into double-quoted strings by inserting spaces between the elements. you can change that behaviour by changing the value of `$"`.

These two examples might look the same, but they are actually very different.